# Volume generated by revolving the region in the first quadrant bounded by the parabolas $y^2=x$, $y^2=8x$, $x^2=y$, $x^2=8y$ about the $x$-axis.

Tags: integration, solid-of-revolution

I came across this question from Schaum's Outlines of Advanced Calculus:

> Show that the volume generated by revolving the region in the first quadrant bounded by the parabolas $y^2=x$, $y^2=8x$, $x^2=y$, $x^2=8y$ about the $x$-axis is $\dfrac{279\pi}{2}$.

My solution was to divide the region into three parts:

[image]

$$\pi\int_{1}^{2}(x^2)^2 - (\sqrt{x})^2\;dx = 4.7\pi$$

$$\pi\int_{4}^{8}(\sqrt{8x})^2 - (\sqrt{x})^2\;dx = 42\pi$$

$$\pi\int_{2}^{4} (x^2)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{8}x^2 \right)^2\;dx = 44.9\pi.$$

Hence the total volume will be

$$\pi(4.7 + 42 + 44.9) = 91.6\pi$$

which is wrong.

Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: Aren't there **four** parts?

Comment: @WeatherVane the parts are three. They are indicated by the two dotted lines drawn. The third part (bounded by $\sqrt{x}$ and $x^2$ for $0\leq x\leq1$) is not included. Even if it is included, it evaluates to $0.3\pi$, so the answer is still wrong.

Comment: Your question mentions **four** bounding parabolas, as shown in the diagram.

Comment: I have drawn the four parabolas. They are drawn in orange ($y=\sqrt{x}$), green ($y=\sqrt{8x}$), violet ($y=x^2$) and black ($y=\frac{1}{8}x^2$).

Comment: Please don't be rude.

Comment: Not trying to be rude, just notifying :)

Comment: There seems to be two finite torus-like bounding volumes when rotated. That between (0, 0) and (1, 1). The other between (0, 0) and (8, 8).

Comment: I am a little confused. I don't think you need the 4th line. The, orange, green and violet line seem to create a region.

Comment: I have this text. What page?

Comment: Also. Now that you've drawn this in desmos. Why not save your graph and paste the link as a comment.

Comment: @Mason the question is on page 240 (in the third edition of the book). I have also added the link in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first term is correct, but the second and third are incorrect.  The correct volume expression should read

$$V = \pi \left(\int_{x=1}^2 (\color{magenta}{x^2})^2 - (\color{orange}{\sqrt{x}})^2 \, dx + \int_{x=2}^4 (\color{green}{\sqrt{8x}})^2 - (\color{orange}{\sqrt{x}})^2 \, dx + \int_{x=4}^8 (\color{green}{\sqrt{8x}})^2 - (x^2/8)^2 \, dx \right).$$

It is worth noting that this is the only region in the first quadrant that is bounded by all four curves.  Admittedly, it is not the most precisely phrased question, but it is reasonable to infer that this is the intended volume.

Comment: Actually I did it the same way, but misevaluated the integral, then copied another solution in my post. Thank you, this helped a lot!

Comment: Actually, I think there's another region that's bounded by the 4 curves. It is the region bounded by the leaf region of $y^2=8x, x^2=8y$ without the small leaf region bounded by $y^2=x, x^2=y$